# Extract a specific element of a table with selenium web driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, data-extraction

Hello I am trying to extract some elements from this website : https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/italy/lega-a-super-cup/sassari-brindisi-rTJFaIyk/

I want the highest odds from home and away team. These data are located at the end of the table and are : 1.31 and 4.57

Here is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/italy/lega-a-super-cup/sassari-brindisi-rTJFaIyk/")

home_average_odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="highest"]/td[contains(@class, "right")]')))]

for i in home_average_odds:
    print(i)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

The problem is that I do not have the good result, here is the output :

```
1.31
4.30
 100.4%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the "good result"?

You can get the avergae by pulling the table with pandas and just pull that row:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/italy/lega-a-super-cup/sassari-brindisi-rTJFaIyk/")
html = driver.page_source

df = pd.read_html(html)[0]

avg = df[df['Bookmakers'] == 'Average']
print (avg)
```

**Output:**

```
print (avg)
   Bookmakers     1     2 Payout Unnamed: 4
49    Average  -408  +291  94.4%        NaN
```

Output matches the table

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your return. But I have exactly the same problem. These are not the same elements. In the webpage for the row "Average" we have : 1,24 3,92  94,1%  but in the output of your way we get 1,24 3,91  94,4%

Comment: Same problem with the last row "Highest" in the webpage we have 1,31 4,57  101,8  whereas in the output using your method we get 1,31 4,3  100,4

Comment: In my case for the last row "Highest the "good result" will be 1,31 4,57  101,8%

Comment: I'm looking at the webpage and output and they are exactly the same. You need to explain more clearly what the issue it. Go to your post and explain the issue more clearly.

Comment: Sorry It was a personal mistake. I ran my script being logged in contrary to you. So In my case I was more bookmakers available so that It was not exactly the same value for Average and Highest.

Comment: Ah ya. That’ll do it. Remember with selenium, you can login and get those numbers.

Comment: Thanks I am trying to log in automatically. I have a little problem. Maybe you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854569/how-to-log-in-with-selenium-webdriver